# ASP.NET Using Entity Framework 5.X Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I decided that constantly writing a long winded code to select data from a table was a bad method to use when I am constantly having to reference between tables, therefore I decided to write a class that handles the queries for me and returns the rows.

```
public Database(object query, object name)
{
    var tbl = (from c in db.name where query select c).ToArray();
    return tbl;
}
```

I am sort of new to Entity and am having a hard time trying to understand the type `name` should be.

At first I tried `object` which gave me this error:

> 'Model.Container' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'Model.rkdb_07022016Entities2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So I knew that the table name I am selecting from cannot be passed through as type `object`.

I took an educated guess and tried to make `name` type `Queryable` but still no luck.

Could anyone possibly point me in the right direction and add some references where I can maybe learn how to tackle these situations in the future?

Thank-you.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the code from Joseph Albahari's PredicateBuilder - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx you should be able to use that as a starting point for what you need

Comment: That actually hits the nail on its head, thank-you for the reference! @NDJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(putting as an answer for future viewers)
You probably want an `Expression<Func<EntityType, bool>>` 
If you need to make it generic, you could build something with T.

As I said in the comment, it's worth taking a look at Joseph Albahari's [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for sample code (or indeed use it as it is powerful)